# Handling dynamic div's in selenium

Tags: c#, list, selenium-webdriver, dynamic

I am using a IWebDriver object.

The Webpage contains dynamic div's. I have used to access the div's(elements) by using Xpath/Id or anything.

So i have tried something like this

```
List<IWebElement> webElement = chromeDriver.FindElements(By.XPath("//*[@id='dp_widgets_simplegrid_Grid_8']/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div"));

int rowsSize = webElement.Size();
```

It gave type casting error.

**Cannot convert
system.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyCollection  to System.Collections.Generic.List**

Then I have tried  like below:

```
IWebElement webElement = chromeDriver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='dp_widgets_simplegrid_Grid_8']/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div"));

int rows = webElement.FindElements(By.TagName("div")).Count;
```

But Still i could not find the list of elements in the dynamic grid.

I want to get the list of div elements . Could anyone give me a little idea about that?

Comment: a sample of the target html would be helpful.  Your current string has two indexers `[1]`, perhaps try removing one or both of those?: `"//*[@id='dp_widgets_simplegrid_Grid_8']/div/div/div/div/div"`