# How to scrape for multiple divs that are generated dynamically using Selenium in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

[How to extract text from divs in Selenium using Python when new divs are added every approx 1 second?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53458309/how-to-extract-text-from-divs-in-selenium-using-python-when-new-divs-are-added-e/53458884#53458884)

Based on the above answer, I have the following code:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait as wait
from selenium import webdriver

chrome_path = r"C:\scrape\chromedriver.exe"

driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_path)
driver.get("https://website.com/")
# Get current divs
messages = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('div_i_am_targeting')
# Print all messages
for message in messages:
    print(message.text)

while True:
    try:
        # Wait up to minute for new message to appear
        wait(driver, 60).until(lambda driver: driver.find_elements_by_class_name('div_i_am_targeting') != messages)
        # Print new message
        for message in [m.text for m in driver.find_elements_by_class_name('div_i_am_targeting') if m not in messages]:
            print(message)
        # Update list of messages
        messages = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('div_i_am_targeting')
    except:
        # Break the loop in case no new messages after minute passed
        print('No new messages')
        break
```

Which works fine and captures all divs on the page as they appear, that match the class specified by `div_i_am_targeting`

The divs on this HTML page are generated dynamically and one div appears about once every second.

The actual structure on the page is like this:

```
<div class="div_i_am_targeting">
...
...
</div>
<div class="div_i_am_targeting">
...
...
</div>
<div class="div_i_am_targeting">
...
...
</div>
<div class="some_other_div">
...
...
</div>
<div class="div_i_am_targeting">
...
...
</div>
<div class="yet_another_div">
...
...
</div>
<div class="div_i_am_targeting">
...
...
</div>
```

Such that, in the dynamically created content there are other divs appearing between the div I am currently targeting.

The frequency of divs on the page is variable.

I couldn't find any related questions here, or examples in the documentation.

How can I modify the above code, so that it scrapes the value of more than one div, e.g. if I want to scrape all instances of `div_i_am_targeting` *and* `some_other_div` in the above example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to replace

```
driver.find_elements_by_class_name('div_i_am_targeting')
```

with

```
driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('.div_i_am_targeting, .some_other_div')
```

in your script to match both divs

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. I tried this, but received an error message: "selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidSelectorException: Message: invalid selector: Compound class names not permitted"

Comment: @Gary , that's because you're still using `find_elements_by_class_name` while you should use `find_elements_by_css_selector`